# HtmlUnit - HtmlPage com caracteres especiais e formatação diferente

Tags: java

Uso [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) e quando vou dar um webClient.getPage() em uma url, recebo um [HtmlPage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html) dessa forma (htmlPage.asXml()):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="scripts/RelatorioGerencial_Resultados.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="dumpContent()">
    ÿþ&lt; s t y l e &gt; 
 
 
 
                   . f i l t r o 
 
                                 { 
 
                                 h e i g h t :   5 0 % ; 
 
                                 b o r d e r :             1 p x   o u t s e t ; 
 
                                 f o n t - f a m i l y :   a r i a l ; 
 
                                 f o n t - s i z e :       6 . 5 p t ; 
 
                                 o v e r f l o w - y :   s c r o l l ; 
 
                                 b a c k g r o u n d - c o l o r :   d 1 d 6 e 7 ; 
 
                                 } 
 
 
 
                   . f i l t r o T e x t o I n p u t 
 
                                 { 
 
                                 f o n t - f a m i l y :   a r i a l ; 
 
                                 f o n t - s i z e :       6 . 5 p t ; 
 
                                 b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   b l u e ; 
 
                                 } 
 
 
 
                     &lt; / s t y l e &gt; &lt; s c r i p t &gt; 
 
   / /   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
 
   f u n c t i o n   P o i n t ( i n X ,   i n Y ) 
 
     { 
 
     t h i s . X   =   i n X ; 
 
     t h i s . Y   =   i n Y ;     
 
     } 
 
     
 
   / /   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -     
 
   f u n c t i o n   g e t A b s o l u t e C o o r d i n a t e s ( o b j ) 
 
     { 
 
     v a r   r e t u r n X = 0 ; 
 
     v a r   r e t u r n Y = 0 ; 
 
     v a r   r e t u r n P o i n t ; 
 
     
 
     f o r ( ; o b j . o f f s e t P a r e n t ; o b j = o b j . o f f s e t P a r e n t ) 
 
       { 
 
       r e t u r n X + = o b j . o f f s e t P a r e n t . o f f s e t L e f t ; 
 
       r e t u r n Y + = o b j . o f f s e t P a r e n t . o f f s e t T o p ; 
 
       } 
 
       
 
     r e t u r n P o i n t   =   n e w   P o i n t ( r e t u r n X , r e t u r n Y ) ; 
 
     r e t u r n   ( r e t u r n P o i n t ) ; 
 
     } 
 
 
 
   / /   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -         
 
   f u n c t i o n   s t a r t U p ( s t r L a b e l ) 
 
     { 
 
     v a r   i S e n d e r D i v ; 
 
     
 
       
 
       v a r   a r r O b j B a s e   =   p a r e n t . d o c u m e n t . g e t E l e m e n t s B y N a m e ( ' b a s e O b j ' ) ; 
 
         f o r   ( i = 0 ;   i &lt;   a r r O b j B a s e . l e n g t h ;   i + + )           
 
         i f ( a r r O b j B a s e [ i ] . n a m e = = s t r L a b e l )   i S e n d e r D i v   =   a r r O b j B a s e [ i ] ; 
 
       
 
       v a r   P = g e t A b s o l u t e C o o r d i n a t e s ( i S e n d e r D i v ) ;       
 
       
 
       p a r e n t . f i l t r o . n a m e   =   s t r L a b e l ; 
 
       
 
       p a r e n t . f i l t r o . i n n e r H T M L   =   r e t u r n V a l u e . i n n e r H T M L ; 
 
     p a r e n t . f i l t r o . s t y l e . t o p = P . Y + i S e n d e r D i v . o f f s e t H e i g h t ; 
 
     p a r e n t . f i l t r o . s t y l e . l e f t = P . X ; 
 
     p a r e n t . f i l t r o . s t y l e . v i s i b i l i t y = ' v i s i b l e ' ; 
 
     p a r e n t . f i l t r o . s t y l e . d i s p l a y = ' b l o c k ' ; 
 
     p a r e n t . g e t F i l t e r V a l u e ( s t r L a b e l ) ; 
 
     } 
 
     
 
   / /   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   - 
 
   f u n c t i o n   S e l e c t F i l t e r ( )   
 
     { 
 
     f i l t e r F i e l d . v a l u e = " " ; 
 
     
 
     v a r   i n p u t F i l t e r s   =   d o c u m e n t . g e t E l e m e n t s B y N a m e ( ' f i l t e r I D ' ) ; 
 
     f o r   ( K   i n   i n p u t F i l t e r s ) 
 
       i f   ( i n p u t F i l t e r s [ K ] . c h e c k e d = = t r u e )   f i l t e r F i e l d . v a l u e + = " ' " + i n p u t F i l t e r s [ K ] . v a l u e + " ' " ; 
 
     / / a l e r t ( f i l t e r F i e l d . v a l u e ) ; 
 
     } 
 
       &lt; / s c r i p t &gt; &lt; t e x t A r e a   i d = " t x t Q u e r y "   s t y l e = " w i d t h :   1 0 0 % ;   h e i g h t :   1 0 0 % ;   b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   r e d ;   f o n t - f a m i l y :   c o u r i e r   n e w "   o n D b l C l i c k = " t h i s . c r e a t e T e x t R a n g e ( ) . e x e c C o m m a n d ( ' S e l e c t A l l ' ) ; t h i s . c r e a t e T e x t R a n g e ( ) . e x e c C o m m a n d ( ' C o p y ' ) ;   t h i s . c r e a t e T e x t R a n g e ( ) . e x e c C o m m a n d ( ' U n s e l e c t ' ) ;   a l e r t ( ' Q u e r y   C o p i a d a   p a r a   a   Á r e a   d e   T r a n s f e r ê n c i a ' ) " &gt; S e l e c t   t o p ( 2 0 0 0 0 0 )     [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   A s   [ C ó d .   C a u s a ] , 
 
               [ C A U S A ] . [ D T _ C A D A S T R A M E N T O ]   A s   [ D t .   C a d a s t r a m e n t o   ( R e g i s t r o ) ] , 
 
               [ C O R P _ R E C U R S O _ H U M A N O _ R E S P _ C A U S A ] . [ I D _ L A P ]   A s   [ R e s p .   C a d a s t r a m e n t o   ( R e g i s t r o ) ] , 
 
               [ C A U S A ] . [ S T _ C A U S A ]   A s   [ S t a t u s   C a u s a ] , 
 
               [ S E R V I C O _ A ] . [ C D _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   A s   [ N º   A ] , 
 
               [ C O R P _ U F _ A  ] . [ D S _ M U N I C I P I O ]   A s   [ M u n i c i p i o ] , 
 
               [ C O R P _ U F _ A ] . [ C D _ U F ]   A s   [ U F ] , 
 
               [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ D T _ A N D A M E N T O ]   A s   [ D t .   A n d a m e n t o ] , 
 
               [ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O _ F A S E ] . [ D S _ F A S E _ A N D A M E N T O ]   A s   [ F a s e ] 
 
 
 
     F R O M   [ C A U S A ] 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N   [ C O R P _ R E C U R S O _ H U M A N O ]   [ C O R P _ R E C U R S O _ H U M A N O _ R E S P _ C A U S A ]   
 
         O N   [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ R E S P _ C A D A S T R A M E N T O ]   =   [ C O R P _ R E C U R S O _ H U M A N O _ R E S P _ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ R E C U R S O ] 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N   [ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   [ S E R V I C O ]   
 
         O N   [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   =   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ] 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N   [ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   [ S E R V I C O _ A ]   
 
         O N   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   =   [ S E R V I C O _ A E J ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ] 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   =   [ S E R V I C O _ A  ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ] 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ N U _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   =   [ S E R V I C O _ A ] . [ N U _ A T E N D I M E N T O ] 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O _ A  ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   =   ' A  ' 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N   [ D E N O M I N A C A O ]   [ D E N O M I N A C A O _ A E J ]   
 
         O N   [ S E R V I C O _ A  ] . [ I D _ D E N O M I N A C A O ]   =   [ D E N O M I N A C A O _ A  ] . [ I D _ D E N O M I N A C A O ] 
 
   
 
   I N N E R   J O I N   [ C O R P _ U F _ M U N I C I P I O ]   [ C O R P _ U F _ A  ]   
 
         O N   [ D E N O M I N A C A O _ A  ] . [ C D _ U F ]   =   [ C O R P _ U F _ A E J ] . [ C D _ U F ] 
 
       A N D   [ D E N O M I N A C A O _ A E J ] . [ C D _ M U N I C I P I O ]   =   [ C O R P _ U F _ A E J ] . [ C D _ M U N I C I P I O ] 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N     [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ]   
 
         O N   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   =   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ] 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   =   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ] 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O ] . [ N U _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   =   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ N U _ A T E N D I M E N T O ] 
 
 
 
     L E F T   O U T E R   J O I N   [ F A S E _ A N D A M E N T O ]   [ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O _ F A S E ]   
 
         O N   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ I D _ F A S E _ A N D A M E N T O ]   =   [ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O _ F A S E ] . [ I D _ F A S E _ A N D A M E N T O ] 
 
   
 
   I N N E R   J O I N   [ V W _ R G E R _ V I S I B I L I D A D E _ C A U S A _ C O O R D E N A D O R ]   [ V W _ R G E R _ V I S I B I L I D A D E _ C A U S A ]   
 
         O N   [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   =   [ V W _ R G E R _ V I S I B I L I D A D E _ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ] 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ V I S I B I L I D A D E _ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ R E C U R S O ]   =   ' - 5 0 0 ' 
 
 
 
   W H E R E   [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ O R I G E M ]   =   ' M  ' 
 
       A N D   [ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ U N I D A D E ]   =   ' 1 0 3 ' 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ V I S I B I L I D A D E _ C A U S A ] . [ C D _ R E C U R S O ]   =   ' - 5 0 0 ' 
 
       A N D   [ S E R V I C O _ A  ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   = ' A  ' 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ C D _ C A U S A ]   I S   N O T   N U L L 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ C D _ T I P O _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   I S   N O T   N U L L 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ N U _ A T E N D I M E N T O ]   I S   N O T   N U L L 
 
       A N D   [ V W _ R G E R _ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O ] . [ C D _ A N D A M E N T O ]   I S   N O T   N U L L 
 
       A N D   [ A N D A M E N T O _ A N D A M E N T O _ F A S E ] . [ D S _ F A S E _ A N D A M E N T O ]   I N   ( ' G D O C ' ) &lt; / t e x t A r e a &gt; &lt; b o d y &gt; 
 
 &lt; d i v   s t y l e = " d i s p l a y :   n o n e " &gt; 
 
 &lt; t a b l e &gt; 
 
 &lt; t r &gt; 
 
 &lt; t d &gt; 
 
 &lt; d i v   i d = " c o n t r o l e L o t e " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   t y p e = " h i d d e n "   i d = " x m l L o t e "   n a m e = " x m l L o t e "   v a l u e = " " &gt; &lt; b u t t o n   v a l u e = " "   n a m e = " l o a d L o t e "   i d = " l o a d L o t e "   s t y l e = " f o n t - f a m i l y :   v e r d a n a ;   f o n t - s i z e :   7 p t ;   c u r s o r :   p o i n t e r ; "   o n c l i c k = " l o a d L o t e ( x m l L o t e ) " &gt; &lt; i m g   s r c = " i m a g e s / u p l o a d _ l o t e . g i f "   a l i g n = " a b s M i d d l e " &gt;     C a r r e g a r   L o t e   (   &lt; s p a n   i d = " t a m L o t e "   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   0 p x "   n a m e = " t a m L o t e " &gt; 0 &lt; / s p a n &gt;   ) &lt; / b u t t o n &gt; &lt; b u t t o n   v a l u e = " "   n a m e = " c l e a r L o t e "   i d = " c l e a r L o t e "   s t y l e = " f o n t - f a m i l y :   v e r d a n a ;   f o n t - s i z e :   7 p t ;   c u r s o r :   p o i n t e r ; "   o n c l i c k = " c l e a r L o t e ( ) " &gt; &lt; i m g   s r c = " / i m a g e s / l i m p a r . g i f "   a l i g n = " a b s M i d d l e "   s t y l e = " v e r t i c a l - a l i g n :   m i d d l e " &gt;     L i m p a r   L o t e   &lt; / b u t t o n &gt; &lt; / d i v &gt; 
 
 &lt; / t d &gt; 
 
 &lt; t d &gt; 
 
 &lt; D I V   I D = " P a g i n g C o n t r o l " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   i d = " f i s t P a g e "   t y p e = " b u t t o n "   s t y l e = " c u r s o r :   h a n d ;   b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   # 9 9 C ;   "   o n C l i c k = " g o F i r s t P a g e ( ) "   v a l u e = " | &lt; " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   i d = " p r e v i o u w P a g e "   t y p e = " b u t t o n "   s t y l e = " c u r s o r :   h a n d ;   b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   # 9 9 C "   o n C l i c k = " g o P r e v i o u s P a g e ( ) "   v a l u e = " &lt; "   d i s a b l e d = " t r u e " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   i d = " c u r r e n t P a g e "   d i s a b l e d = " t r u e "   s t y l e = " b o r d e r : 1     p x   i n s e t ;   w i d t h :   1 p x ;   m a r g i n :   0 p x   0 p x   1 p x   0 p x ;   o v e r f l o w : v i s i b l e "   v a l u e = "   1   /   1   " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   i d = " f i s t P a g e "   t y p e = " b u t t o n "   s t y l e = " c u r s o r :   h a n d ;   b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   # 9 9 C "   o n C l i c k = " g o N e x t P a g e ( ) "   v a l u e = " &gt; "   d i s a b l e d = " t r u e " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   i d = " p r e v i o u w P a g e "   t y p e = " b u t t o n "   s t y l e = " c u r s o r :   h a n d ;   b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   # 9 9 C "   o n C l i c k = " g o L a s t P a g e ( ) "   v a l u e = " &gt; | " &gt; &lt; / D I V &gt; 
 
 &lt; / t d &gt; 
 
 &lt; / t r &gt; 
 
 &lt; / t a b l e &gt; 
 
 &lt; T A B L E   b o r d e r = " 1 "   w i d t h = " 1 0 0 % " &gt; 
 
 &lt; T B O D Y   I D = " R e s u l t S e t " &gt; 
 
 &lt; T R &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 2 . 1 8 8 1 8 3 8 0 7 4 3 9 8 2 4 7 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; &lt; i n p u t   t y p e = " c h e c k b o x "   n a m e = " l o t e "   i d = " l o t e "   o n c l i c k = " c h e c k M e ( t h i s ) "   v a l u e = " T R I 0 0 5 0 3 0 4 " &gt; &lt; A   h r e f = " / P a g i n a s / P r o n t u a r i o _ J u r i d i c o / G e r e n c i a _ A t e n d i m e n t o / L o t e / c a r r e g a r C a u s a . a s p ? c d _ C a u s a = T R I 0 0 5 0 3 0 4 " &gt; T P I 0 0 7 0 3 0 4 &lt; / A &gt; &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 3 . 5 0 1 0 9 4 0 9 1 9 0 3 7 2 % "   a l i g n = " c e n t e r "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; 1 9 / 0 8 / 2 0 1 9 &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 5 . 2 5 1 6 4 1 1 3 7 8 5 5 5 8 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; s c o r . p m e d e i r o s &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 1 . 9 6 9 3 6 5 4 2 6 6 9 5 8 4 2 4 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; E M   C U R S O &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 5 . 4 7 0 4 5 9 5 1 8 5 9 9 5 6 2 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; 0 1 0 0 1 3 3 6 0 1 9 2 5 &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 5 5 . 7 9 8 6 8 7 0 8 9 7 1 5 5 3 6 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; U B E R A B A &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 0 . 4 3 7 6 3 6 7 6 1 4 8 7 9 6 5 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; M G &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 3 . 5 0 1 0 9 4 0 9 1 9 0 3 7 2 % "   a l i g n = " c e n t e r "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; 1 9 / 0 8 / 2 0 1 0 &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; T D   s t y l e = " b o r d e r :   1 p x   s o l i d   l i g h t g r e y ;   b o r d e r - r i g h t :   1 p x   s o l i d   d a r k g r e y ;   p a d d i n g :   0 p x   1 0 p x   0 p x   1 0   p x "   c l a s s = " R e s u l t C e l l "   w i d t h = " 2 1 . 8 8 2 8 3 8 0 7 7 3 9 8 2 5 % "   a l i g n = " l e f t "   n o w r a p = " 1 " &gt; G D O C &lt; / T D &gt; 
 
 &lt; / T R &gt; 
 
 &lt; / T B O D Y &gt; 
 
 &lt; / T A B L E &gt; 
 
 &lt; D I V   I D = " T o t a l " &gt; R e g i s t r o   L o c a l i z a d o :   &lt; s t r o n g &gt; 1 &lt; / s t r o n g &gt;   &lt; / D I V &gt; 
 
 &lt; / d i v &gt; 
 
 &lt; / b o d y &gt; 
 
 

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    try{
        parent.document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display = 'none';
        parent.$('.botoes').show('slow');
    }
    catch(e){
    }

//]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Código de requisição:**

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebClientFactory.getWebRequest("https://siteConfidencial/RelatorioGerencial_Resultado.asp", HttpMethod.POST);
        final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        String entidade = Util.getEncoded("<Atributos><pagina>0</pagina><lote></lote></Atributos>");
        String atributo = Util.getEncoded("atributosTeste");

params.add(new NameValuePair("Entidade", entidade));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("Atributo", atributo));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("label", ""));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("xmlLote", ""));
        params.add(new NameValuePair("filtroResumo", ""));
        webRequest.setRequestBody(params.stream().map(NameValuePair::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("&")));

HtmlPage finalPage = WebClientFactory.getPage(webRequest);
```

**Configurações do webClient:**

```
   public static synchronized WebClient getInstance() {
                if (WebClientFactory.THREAD_LOCAL_WEB_CLIENT.get() == null) {
                    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);
                    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
                    webClient.setAlertHandler(new CollectingAlertHandler());
                    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
                    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
                    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
                    webClient.getOptions().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
                    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
                    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
                    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
                    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
                    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
                    webClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "pt-BR");
                    webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0);
                    WebClientFactory.THREAD_LOCAL_WEB_CLIENT.set(webClient);
                }
                return WebClientFactory.THREAD_LOCAL_WEB_CLIENT.get();
            }
```

Precisava acessar as tds (uso xpath) mas não consigo. O que seria melhor a se fazer?

Comment: Incluido requisição e configurações do webClient